# I want to disable a button and only enable it when changing the form in vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, lodash

I need help with a question, I am two trying to make a disabled save button be enabled when someone changes the form for two days, I realized today that the purchase I'm doing `lodash` is not working, whenever I change something in the form so much the oldForm variable as the form, are also changed, I've done everything and even so I couldn't enable the button.

Button component code in `vuejs`

```html
<template>
    <div
        v-bind:class="isActive()"
        class="flex w-max rounded text-xs">
        <inertia-link class="py-2 px-6 uppercase" v-if="href" :href="href">
            <slot></slot>
        </inertia-link>
        <button v-if="!href"
                disabled="!changed"
                class="py-2 px-6 uppercase" type="button">
            <slot></slot>
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
    props: {
        href: String,
        active: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
        },
        form:{
            type: Object
        },
        processing: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },
    data(){
        return{
            changed: false,
        }
    },
    computed:{
        oldForm(){
            return this.form;
        }
    },
    watch:{
        oldForm(){
            this.oldForm = _.cloneDeep(this.form)
        },
        form:{
            handler(){
                this.changed = !_.isEqual(this.form, this.oldForm)
                console.log(this.form)
                console.log(this.oldForm)

            },
            deep: true,


        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Calling the button on the form:

```html
<submit-button
     :processing="form.processing"
     :form="form"
     :active="isFormChanged" @click.native="save()">
    <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Salvar
</submit-button>
```

With `console.log`, I found they were the same, how do I store one and compare with the other to enable the button?

I can only use `VueJS` and `lodash` to solve this.